# Can the .fbx file format or the .dwf file format hold Product Manufacturing Information (PMI) data?

Tags: file-format, cad, fbx

Is there somewhere I can find information about these 3D file formats or other ones? I am particularly interested in seeing which file formats can hold PMI data?

Answer (score 2):

**[Product Manufacturing Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_and_manufacturing_information)** (PMI) is usually defined by the following components:

- **[GD&T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_dimensioning_and_tolerancing)** (geometrical dimensioning and tolerancing).
- 3D annotations / symbols.
- Captured views.

These might be also represented in [two ways](http://www.ap242.org/geometry-assembly-pmi-interoperability) in format:

- **Graphical representation** (how to actually display information in 3D viewer - usually in form of pre-tessellated geometry).
- **Semantic representation** (just marks / annotates real geometry with extra information; it is up to the application how to use / display this information to user).

There are two key ISO standardized file formats that mentions **PMI** explicitly:

- [STEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_10303) (most noticeably **AP242**). Here is a [live example](https://pages.nist.gov/CAD-PMI-Testing/graphical-pmi-viewer.html) of GD&T in STEP.
- [JT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JT_(visualization_format)) (mostly promoted by a single vendor).

Proprietary and native file formats (specific to one product) might also support PMI (like [Catia V5 / SOLIDWORKS](https://www.solidworks.com/sw/products/details.htm?ID=469&productid=305)), but they are not expected to be used for data exchange. I don't think that FBX has anything directly related to PMI.

There are might be more formats supporting PMI (3D PDF?), but I haven't seen much information about that.